# C# binary cmdlet with IDynamicParameters

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline

I wrote simple cmdlet:

```
public class UserCredential
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public PSCredential Credential { get; set; }
}

[Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "Pipeline")]
public class TestPipeline : Cmdlet, IDynamicParameters
{
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    private UserCredential userCredential;
    public Object GetDynamicParameters()
    {
        if ((Id != null) && (Id.Equals("c01")))
        {
            userCredential = new UserCredential();
            return userCredential;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        string userName = "Not set";
        string userPassword = "Not set";
        if(userCredential != null)
        {
            userName = userCredential.Credential.UserName;
            userPassword = userCredential.Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password;
        }
        WriteObject(string.Format("Id {0} N {1} P {2}", Id, userName, userPassword));
    }
}
```

Idea is simple: Cmdlet have to ask about credentials when Id is equal to c01. This is done when I call cmdlet:

Test-Pipeline -Id c01

credential dialog appears.

but when I use pipeline:

"c01"|Test-Pipeline

Id is bind but credential dialog isn;t showed. 
In article [Cmdlet life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714429(v=vs.85).aspx) . Microsoft explains this and writes that after call BeginProcessing() method pipeline arguments are binded and dynamics parameter are binded too. What is wrong in my code? GetDynamicParameters() method is called only one, before binding pipeline arguments.
I can use Invoke() method from PowerShell class in ProcessRecord() method but this isn't my prefered solution.